# rename navigation menu label in wordpress theme by code

Tags: menus

Hello there i have a navigation menu in my wordpress theme. The navigation menu has two items. One has the label “home” and the other “categories”. I need to rename the label “home” to something else and the “categories” label name as well. How is this possible on the fly?

Comment: Have you logged into WordPress, in the sidebar go to Appearance > Menus? After you add a link to a menu, you can change the label of the menu item.

Comment: I need to change it by code because i have to check for if statement first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try filtering just the menu items you want when they get printed back on the front end. You can do that in functions.php

Here you can filter the HTML list content for navigation menus.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

After some talk, give this a try and then call your `lo()` where you need it:

```
function lo() { 
  add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'dynamic_label_change', 10, 2 ); 

  function dynamic_label_change( $items,$args) { 

    if($args->theme_location == 'primary'){ 
      $items = str_replace("Categories", "new_string", $items); 
      $items = str_replace("Latest Offers", "another_new_string", $items); 
    } 
    return $items; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: How do i call this function?

Comment: You can drop this snippet into your functions.php file.

Comment: Ok but how the call should be made from another php file? I need to call it whenever i want...

Comment: If you'd like, you can drop this in any theme file really. It is going to filter out the nav items that are printed back from `wp_nav_menu()`. Which theme file are you trying to work with?

Comment: I mean what needs to be passed with the function $items, $args ...

Comment: add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'dynamic_label_change', 10, 2 ); This filters the items and calls the function?

Comment: Header.php i use to call the add filter but does not work although i check it goes to the str_replace part

Comment: Are you calling it after the `wp_nav_menu()` call? `str_replace` is case sensitive, you might could try `str_ireplace` for the case insensitive version of it.

Comment: wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'boxwp-menu-primary-navigation', 'menu_class' => 'boxwp-nav-primary-menu boxwp-menu-primary', 'fallback_cb' => 'boxwp_fallback_menu', ) );
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'dynamic_label_change', 10, 2 ); If i call it after the wp_nav_menu it does not get called. Only if i put the add filter before the wp_nav_menu it is get called. I tried the str_ireplace but no luck!

Comment: Should it be called after the wp_nav_menu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95630/discussion-between-christopherjones-and-stefanosn).